# Google Sheets - Data Validation - Multi-Select apps script - Error Message

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multi-select

I am just learning Apps Scripts, I don't have a lot of experience writing code. Google Sheets in-built data validation feature allows one to choose a "single" option from a dropdown list, however I need my Google Sheet to allow for choosing multiple options for a cell from a list of options.

After browsing the Internet, I found an Apps Script for the job and it works, yay! However, when multiple items are selected, an error message appears in the cell:

Invalid:
Input must be an item on the specified list

Below is the script I have been using.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (activeCell.getColumn() == 6 && activeCell.getLastRow && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Template") {
    newValue = e.value;
    oldValue = e.oldValue;
    if (!e.value) {
      activeCell.setValue("");
    }
    else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        activeCell.setValue(newValue);
      }
      else {
        activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to remove that warning. The new values set by the script are comma-separated texts that are not in the original list of accepted values. - You might want to look into building a list with checkboxes and learn the formula FILTER() to get your values

Comment: Do you have a snapshot of your dropdown and output w warning? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Tried your code I think there's a slight issue with this code, you can select the same item multiple times. And also you won't be able to remove the warning.

### SUGGESTION / Alternate solution

Here's another way to do it using apps script and custom menu, without an error or warning:

1.) Go to Extensions > Apps Script...
You should have this
[image]
2.) Rename the **Code.gs** to **SERVER.gs** and delete current content. Now paste here the codes from below

```
/**
 * Changes the variable validation if needed
 */

var validation = {
    sheet: 'VALIDATION',
    range: 'A2:A'
}

/**
 * Creates a menu entry in the Google Docs UI when the document is opened.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Sidebar')
        .addItem('Show Sidebar', 'showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
        showSidebar();
}


/**
 * Opens a sidebar in the document containing the add-on's user interface.
 */

function showSidebar() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .showSidebar(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('SIDEBAR')
            .evaluate()
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
            .setTitle('Multiple selector'));
}

function getOptions() {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(validation.sheet).getRange(validation.range).getDisplayValues()
        .filter(String)
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a.concat(b)
        })
}

function process(arr) {
    arr.length > 0 ? SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().clearContent().setValue(arr.join(", ")) :
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No options selected')
}
```

3.) Create a new file in the script editor by clicking the Plus(+) sign then click HTML.

4.) Delete the content and paste here the codes from below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    .container,
    .buttons {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 95%;
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <p>
            <button class="action" id="action">Fill active cell</button>
            <button id="btn">Rebuild options</button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            createList();
            var selected = [];
            $('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();
            $("#action").click(function() {
                $("input:checkbox[name=sel]:checked").each(function() {
                    selected.push($(this).val());
                    $(this).prop( "checked", false ); 
                });
                google.script.run.process(selected)
                selected.length = 0;
            });
            $("#btn").click(function() {
                createList();
            });
        });

        function options(arr) {
            $(".container").empty();
            $(arr).each(function(i, el) {
                $(".container").append('<div class="field"><div class="ui checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="sel" value="' + el + '"><label>' + el + '</label></div></div>')
            });
        }

        function createList() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(options).getOptions()
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

5.) Refresh your spreadsheet you should now have the custom menu **Sidebar**. [image]

6.) Add a sheet named "Validation" here is where you will put the options available to select. Start from the row 2.

[image]

7.) Go back to your main sheet, select the cell where you want to input the options. Click Sidebar > **Show Sidebar**. A side bar should open  on the right with the list of options that you have added in the validation sheet.

[image]

8.) You can now select multiple items from the options.

Let me know if this works!

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gsnzgvvx2y8 , option 1